# Install software during remote session without first logging user out?

Tags: permissions, installation, remote-desktop, remote-access

Users do not have administrative privileges, which restricts them from installing software, so they must reach out for support.

However, for an administrator to install software, the user must first log out of their active session, only after which the admin can log into the local administrator account on the machine and install the program.

Is there any way to install the software while without first closing the active user session when remote screen sharing?

Answer (score 2):

Have the administrator run the installer as Administrator.

Comment: That approach still requires the user to log out of their current session, though. Or am I incorrect?

Comment: @toolshed You're incorrect. See also `runas`, `psexec`, among other options.

Comment: @jscott is there a method to do this in the GUI, though? I would rather not save the credential, in case someone forgets to remove it. Sorry for being ignorant. I've searched Google, but the best I could find were hacks.

Comment: None of these methods save the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can allow users to install programs themselves.  This would require you to have SCCM services setup on your server and clients.  Once you have that setup, you can enable virtual applications installation.  There's more on it here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161869.aspx